# Is there any method to update a json object and print it as json object in a div using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have updated my jSon object using the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                var lessonId = "3423671";
                $.getJSON('data.json', function(json) {             
                    $.each(json, function(i, data) {
                        $.each(this.courseStarted[0].courseDetails[0].lessonDetails, function(){                            
                            if(this.lessonId == lessonId){                              
                                this.quiz = "This row updated";                             
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });

            });
        </script>
```

Here i am updating my `json` object inside the if condition. Is there any method to get me the new updated `json` object to print into a html div tag as text in the `json format`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `json` has your object data (retrieved from your server), and your code just updated it, you can transform it into a string again using `JSON.stringify(json)`. AFAIK the `JSON` object is natively supported in most browsers.

Comment: It is working in all browsers except iE7. Is there any code which is working in IE7 also?

Comment: Well, you could go to [json.org](http://json.org) and download the file `json2.js`, it will provide a `JSON` object if your browser doesn't have one, and fall back to the native object if it has.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.stringify({ foo: "lorem", bar: "ipsum" }, null, '\t');
```

[doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#space_argument)